# Realtime database is not showing data that is being written from android studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem writing into Firebase real-time database.
The app is running fine with no build errors. but when I look into the database nothing is changing. I am trying to write into the database. The account which is logged in in Android and Firebase is the same. I have also given the internet permission in the manifest file. I have included the JSON file in the project. I have added all the required dependencies in gradle. the gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.firebasehometry'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.firebasehometry"
    minSdk 25
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
 }

dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.5.1'
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
 id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
```

}

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference reference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://fir-home- 
53258-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
    reference = database.getReference("student");
add();
}
public void add(){
    reference.setValue("ashar khan");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While describing the issue is important, it's equally important to include the code you've attempted in the question as well. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)